# Fetch all uid from firebase database using swift code

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have this database (see the link above with the image) and a code with a path, that leads to the destination using:

```
databaseReference.child("users").child(currentUser!.uid).child("todo-list")
```

[image: Firebase database structure]

Under the first node "users", the next level is a keyvalue for userID, and later there are more sub-levels "todo-list" etc.

I would like to fetch the data from **all uid** available. How can I make the query?

Here is the code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    databaseReference = Database.database().reference()
    currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let todoListRef = databaseReference.child("users").child(currentUser!.uid).child("todo-list")
    todoListRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (DataSnapshot) in
        self.itemsToLoad.removeAll()
        let enumerator = DataSnapshot.children

        while let todoItem = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot
        {
            let item = todoItem.value as AnyObject

            self.itemsToLoad.append(item)
        }
        self.itemsToLoad = self.itemsToLoad.reversed()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite similar to the code you already have. Instead of observing `/users/$uid`, you observe the entire `/users` node. And then you add an extra loop in the closure, to iterate over all the users.

So:

```
let usersRef = databaseReference.child("users")
usersRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (usersSnapshot) in
  let userEnumerator = usersSnapshot.children
  while let user = userEnumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
    let uid = user.key
    let todoEnumerator = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "todo-list").children

    while let todoItem = todoEnumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
        let item = todoItem.value as AnyObject

        self.itemsToLoad.append(item)
    }
  }
})
```

The added `while` loops over the users, while the inner `while` loops over the todo's for each user. I removed the code related to the table view, since what you want to do there doesn't depend on Firebase.

Comment: Hi Frank! 

Thank you very much, it worked fine to loop todo-list from all users. 
As we can see in the image on the post, the todo-list has a sub-level with a key and under this key  some fields like clientName, etc. Here is ok.

But, on the same level of todo-list, there is another node userDetails. Here there is no sub-level... just some fields like phone and age.
If I change in the code provided from you user.childSnapshot(forPath: "todo-list").children for user.childSnapshot(forPath: "userDetails").children it is not working.

Can you please clarify and show me what is wrong?

Comment: That seems like a different problem, so I'd post a new question for it. Note though that nesting multiple entity types into a single list is an anti-pattern in Firebase. I highly recommend that you create two top-level lists, one with the user data for each user (`/users/$uid: { phone: ..., age: ...}`) and one with the todo-lists for each user (`/todo-lists/$uid: { "15394...": { team: "default", ... } }`).

Comment: Hi Puf, thanks for your response. I will try that and come back later with comments.